# Permission API: Storing access token and token secret for a later use

Tags: paypal

I am using Permissions API to retrieve access token and token secret in order to create "X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION" to process the Refund operation. In order to create the header, I am using PayPal SDK (OAuthSignature.getFullAuthString).
Should I be persisting access token and token secret and create header each time I make an API call?
Or is the header (String retuned by getFullAuthString) reusable forever?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should generate the header every time you make the call, because it has a limited lifespan.

In practice, paypal never expires the authorization header, so you can re-use it.

They might fix it some day, so it's better to stick to the standards, and generate a new header each time.

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. If you support multiple APIs which requires a header, you need to create headers with different URIs anyways so I will persist token and token secret to re-generate header each time. Thanks!